NIFI: POST InvokeHTTP URL local (The URL is provided by IDE Visual Studio.)
I want to make a request to an endpoint using InvokeHTTP in NIFI. If I make the request to the published API, for example: 'mydomain.com/api/process', it processes correctly. However, if I make the request to my local URL obtained from Visual Studio, it doesn't process. Is there any configuration I need to make?
I performed tests through Postman and the endpoint processes correctly.

what's the error?

Try catch the request and error and put here.
Example: url, body, params and status code error are necessary.
